# Kivy - How to update label from Urlrequest on_progress / screen refresh

Tags: python, kivy, urlrequest

My screens contain a message field which I want to update through the on_progress callback when invoking heavy duty rest calls.

```
def restprogress(self, current_size, total_size):
    screen = App.get_running_app().current_screen
    print('Loading')
    screen.ids.messagefield.text = 'Loading .'
```

Callback works fine and message is printed. The label text only changes though, if I abort the Urlrequest (to avoid the success message being displayed).

How can I force the screen update before the rest call completes?
Thanks,
Martin

Comment: Post a minimal runnable example.

Comment: The `screen.ids.messagefield.text = 'Loading .'` must be run on the main thread. Perhaps use `Clock.schedule_once()` to accomplish that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks  [John Anderson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7254633/john-anderson),
running the update of the label text from the main thread solved the issue. I achieved this by invoking an update through the Clock.schedule_once() call.